# wordpress upload file error

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have this upload file system in wordpress and everything is working fine but the file wont go into the folder. Here's what i have right now:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

// Change your upload directory
function my_upload_dir(){
    return PLUGIN_DIR . '/uploads/';
}

// Register our path override.
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir' );

// Set where to get the file from
$uploadedfile = $_FILES["attach"];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

// Do the file move
$movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, $upload_overrides);

// Set everything back to normal.
remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir' );

// Return an error if it couldn't be done
if (!$movefile || isset( $movefile['error'])) {
    echo $movefile['error'];
}
```

its seems to be working fine (no errors) but the image wont show in the folder.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are permissions setup correctly between your folders and your server user?

Comment: @Jaxi, im testing it locally so, i guess it should ok, right? when i try to upload them to the wp uploads folder, they seem to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think This code is working Fine.

```
$date=strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $pro_image_name = $date.$_FILES['your Input type File Name']['name'];
    $allowed =  array('gif','png','jpg');
    $ext = pathinfo($pro_image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $root_path = get_template_directory();
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) { ?>
            <span style="font-size:22px; color:red;">Uploaded File Not Supported</span>
   <?php } else {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['updateimg']['tmp_name'],$root_path."/images/".$pro_image_name);

        $image_get_path =  site_url()."/wp-content/themes/prathak/images/".$pro_image_name;
                 update_user_meta(get_current_user_id() , 'userpic' , $image_get_path );


    }
```

Good Luck